How to generate function multiple args types from an object type
type TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT> = {
  type: string,
  data: unknown,
  mockSource?: (type: string, data: unknown) => (Promise<dataT> | dataT),
  defaultDelay?: number,
  settingName?: string,
  requestId?: string | number,
 };

type TMakeEmberPostMessage<dataT> = (
  type: TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>['type'],
  data: TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>['data'],
  mockSource?: TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>['mockSource'],
  defaultDelay?: TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>['defaultDelay'],
  settingName?: TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>['settingName'],
  requestId?: TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>['requestId'],
) => Promise<dataT>;

Is there a way to generate the args type for TMakeEmberPostMessage from TMakeEmberPostMessageParams, without specifying each argument types? That means converting the object type into multiple function argument types.
I can't change TMakeEmberPostMessage params to a single object as it's used in different codebases.
The problem is there are a few functions that are object params, and would like to Pick couple of properties from TMakeEmberPostMessageParams
Like I would like to do,
type TGetEmberUrlParams<dataT = unknown> = {
  route?: string,
  params?: Record<string, unknown>,
  queryParams?: Record<string, unknown>,
  emberMainDomain?: boolean,
  returnUrl?: boolean,
  openInNewTab?: boolean,
} & Pick<TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<dataT>, 'type' | 'mockSource' | 'defaultDelay' | 'settingName'>;


Why is it an object type, rather than a tuple type?

I have other functions with object type that uses makeEmberPostMessage function which is type of TMakeEmberPostMessage, and I don't want to duplicate the object type there, so I would like to create one object type and use it in this function and other functions with objects can use it as well

It's possible, but it's a really really bad idea. First you convert the object type to a tuple (see here and here), then you use (...args: TheTupleType) in the function parameter list. But see the linked answers for why that's a really, really bad idea. :-) As soon as you can feasibly schedule it, I'd schedule the few hours needed to update the calls to the function so you can pass an object instead.

thanks, I would like to use Pick for a few properties as shown in the updated question from the tuple type, so is it better instead to duplicate the type or keep it with what I've right now?

In your first code block, you aren't duplicating the type, you're specifying a list of parameters whose types you get from TMakeEmberPostMessageParams. That seems just fine as it is (temporarily, until you can update the function to accept an object).

You can't do it, no. What if you did something like this, where you write a base tuple which holds the keys and values, and then use it to generate both of TMakeEmberPostMessageParams<T> and TMakeEmberPostMessage<T>? That's easier to maintain (there's some necessary "duplication" with tuple labels if you care about parameter names being the same as the corresponding object keys), although still a lot harder than just having all the functions take a single object. If that fully addresses the question I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
